# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row with cut-off reference

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

i got the following problem:

I would like to create a model entry with pivot. While saving this, I am getting this error:

```
 "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
    (`homestead`.`product_bundle_product_product_bundle_product_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `pb_product_attribute` FOREIGN KEY
    (`product_bundle_product_attribute_id`) REFERENCES `product_bundle_product_)
    (SQL: insert into `product_bundle_product_product_bundle_product_attribute`
    (`custom`, `price`, `product_bundle_product_attribute_id`, `product_bundle_product_id`, `title`, `type`, `unit`, `value`)
    values (1, 2, 1, 1, Test, decimal, GB, 16))",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
    "line": 665,
```

This is the migration that belongs to this:

```
Schema::create('product_bundle_product_product_bundle_product_attribute', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('product_bundle_product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('product_bundle_product_attribute_id')
                ->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('custom')->nullable();
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('unit')->nullable();
            $table->string('type')->nullable();
            $table->text('value')->nullable();
            $table->float('price')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('product_bundle_product_id', 'pb_product')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('product_bundle_products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('product_bundle_product_attribute_id', 'pb_product_attribute')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('product_bundle_product_attributes')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

I was able to run the migration without any problems, but once I am trying to `sync` this, I am getting the error above.

This is my `sync`-statement:

```
        $result = [ 1 => [
            'custom' => true,
            'title' => "Test",
            'unit' => 'GB',
            'type' => "decimal",
            'price' => 2,
            'value' => 16
        ]];

 $this->productAttributes()->sync($result);
```

I saw in the  error message that there's something cut off:

`REFERENCES product_bundle_product_` where it should be `product_bundle_product_attributes`, right?

Comment: Do you have id -> 1 in product attribute table?

Comment: Because it is going to check id in table and not found id in parent table

Comment: Yes, the `ProductAttribute` with `id: 1` does exist.